# Emacs org-mode: wrong indentation and missing stars

Tags: emacs, org-mode

After updating org to the latest version (configuration unchanged), I face the problem that the structure is not displayed properly.

In text mode, the structure looks like this:

`* heading 1
** heading 2
*** heading 3
**** heading 4`

In Org-mode, with `org-indent-mode` switched on, it looks different (note: switching `org-indent-mode` off does only change indentation, not the look):

`* heading 1
  * heading 2
    heading 3
      heading 4`

It seems, that for some reason the indentation for heading 3 and subsequent headings is broken. `org-current-level` returns the correct level for each heading.

This behaviour is reproducable with a clean org file.

System is org 9.1.3, emacs 25.1.1 on Win10.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior: Org mode version 9.1.3 (release_9.1.3-208-g7a3ca), GNU Emacs 27.0.5. Have you tried with`emacs -q`?

Comment: It seems that setting `org-hide-emphasis-marker` caused the problem. Originally I set it to `t` which resulted in the described behaviour. After removing my customization the system now runs as normal.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce it, even after setting `org-hide-emphasis-marker` to `t`.  And I cannot find any commits in the tree that involve org-hide-emphasis-marker. Can you provide a reproducer, starting with `emacs -q`?

Comment: I followed your advice running `emacs -q` and rebuilt my configuration line by line. Unfortunately (for finding the solution) I didn't run into the error again. I think I need some more time to find the bug in my configuration. I keep you updated on my progress.